# Configuring a hierarchical structure with inherited attributes

Tags: hierarchy, structure

The information model of my application consists of a hierarchy of objects (one to many), each has its own specific attributes and inherited attributes. For each inherited attribute in an object, user should be able to specify that either it inherit its value from its parent or that he would like to specifically override it with its own value.

I have come through this [Google Dev Tools view of CSS style hierarchies](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/91221/2625) suggestion for a similar question which I have to say that, though seem rather technical, can suit my users which are very technical by themselves (their alternative up today was to configure it all through CLI). Yet, as suggested in the answer, it has to be adapted and cleaned.

**I am looking for answers suggesting two alternatives:**

1. Completely different approach to the original problem depicted above.
2. A way to adapt/clean/beautify the [Google Dev Tools view of CSS style hierarchies](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/91221/2625) suggestion.

To demonstrate the hierarchy I used Group and Member objects. Group can have zero or many members. Group attributes #1, #2 and #4 are relevant also for members. Each member inherits the values of the group attributes from its group (by default). However, user may override a configuration done in the group with its specific setting (value). For example, the member in the example, has chosen to override Group attribute #2. Member also has some member-only attributes depicted in Attribute set #2.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fek0e6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: do you have any existing wires/screenshots to show what it currently looks like>

Comment: @Midas I do not have but, also if I had, it contains rather technical terms and I do not want it to grab the focus. Anyway, I have added some wireframe depicting the hierarchy and the current solution I have.